# How can a variable be both constexpr and not constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time-constant

I have made a `constexpr` string type, which I call `StaticString`.  I got this idea from [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/482276/c-11-compile-time-string-concatenation-with-constexpr) website.

I am having some weird issues with the compiler treating a variable as a `constexpr` on one line, and then not a `constexpr` on the next line.

Here is the code:

```
constexpr StaticString hello = "hello";
constexpr StaticString hello2 = hello + " ";
constexpr StaticString world = "world";
constexpr StaticString both = hello + " world";
constexpr StaticString both2 = hello2 + world;
//This works fine (world is constexpr?)

//constexpr StaticString both3 = "hello " + world; 
//ERROR: "world" is not constexpr

int main(void)
{
    static_assert(hello[4] == 'o' ,"ERROR");
    static_assert(hello == "hello", "ERROR");
    static_assert(both2 == "hello world", "ERROR");
}
```

And here is the definition of `StaticString`:

```
class StaticString{
        const char* const str;
        const size_t len;
        const StaticString* head;
    public:
        template<size_t N>
        constexpr StaticString(const char(&aStr)[N]) 
            : str(aStr), len(N-1), head(nullptr)  //Chop off the null terminating char
        {
            static_assert(N>=1,"String cannot have a negative length");
        }
        template<size_t N>
        constexpr StaticString(const char(&aStr)[N] ,const StaticString* ss) : head(ss), str(aStr),len(N-1) { }
        constexpr StaticString(const char* const aStr ,const size_t len,const StaticString* ss = nullptr) 
            : str(aStr), len(len), head(ss)
        {
        }
        constexpr char GetFromHead(size_t index) const{
            return index < head->GetSize() ? (*head)[index] : str[index - head->GetSize()];
        }
        constexpr char operator[](size_t index) const{
            return head ? GetFromHead(index) : str[index];
        }
        constexpr size_t GetSize() const{
            return head ? len + head->GetSize() : len;
        }
        constexpr bool Equals(const char* const other,size_t len,size_t index = 0) const{

            return (other[0] == (*this)[index]) ? (len > 1 ? Equals(&other[1],len-1,index+1) : true) : false;
        }
        template<size_t N>
        constexpr bool operator==(const char(&other)[N]) const{
            return Equals(other,N-1);
        }
        template<size_t N>
        constexpr StaticString operator+(const char(&other)[N]) const{
            return StaticString(other,this);
        }
        constexpr StaticString operator+(StaticString other) const{
            return StaticString(other.str,other.len,this);
        }

};
template<size_t N>
constexpr StaticString operator+(const char(&str)[N],const StaticString& other){
    return StaticString(str) + other;
}
```

So my question is this: why does `world` get treated as a `constexpr` on one line but not the next?

**NOTE:** 
This is the error I get:

```
'StaticString{((const char*)"world"), 5ull, ((const prototypeInd::util::StaticString*)(&<anonymous>))}' is not a constant expression
```

Also I am using `gcc`

Comment: Additionally, `hello2 + world + world` will also fail.

Comment: What compiler(s) are you using? VS2015 doesn't generate an error on the declaration/definition of `both3`, but it does crash the compiler when it's used in a `static_assert()`... (C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.)   So I guess that's really not much help.

Comment: Did you solve it? What about updating the question with the corrections you made?

Answer (score 7):

### Discussion

Your `world` variable is `constexpr` but `operator+` in expression:

```
constexpr StaticString both3 = "hello " + world;
```

although marked as `constexpr` is not. Because in its return statement:

```
return StaticString(str) + other;
```

due to the creation of the temporary `StaticString(str)` pointers to non-static-storage duration temporaries are also being created. This is attributed to the fact that in your `StaticString` objects you're storing addresses of non-static-storage duration temporaries and these kind of pointers are not allowed in constant expressions.

### Justification

According to the standard *§5.20/p5 Constant expressions [expr.const]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
>   expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> (5.1) — if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data
>   member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted
>   result of a constant expression,
>
> (5.2) — **if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an
>   object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such
>   an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value,
>   and**
>
> (5.3) — if the value is an object of class or array type, **each
>   subobject satisfies these constraints for the value.**
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an
>   object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary
>   object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above
>   constraints, or it is a function.

.

Comment: @Cornstalks, because the left-hand side is not a `StaticString`.

Comment: Also, "other + str" is not the same as "str + other".

Comment: @zneak that comment is correct Corntalks was referring to my first mistaken answer :(

Comment: As zneak said unfortunately I cannot use your solution because `other + string` is different than `string + other` this is the difference between creating the strings "hello world" and " worldhello"

Comment: @DarthRubik hmm... you're right, I'll try to give another solution.

Comment: I think you want to replace the one staticstring with a `std::array`-like family, where concatination builds a larger one *containing the data*.  Then the pointers-to-non-static-storage problem evaporates.  Strings are actually concatinated at compile time as well.  Unfortunetally the lack of the `char...` overload of `operator""` for strings means we cannot easily store the string purely in the type.

Comment: @Yakk The only problem is you cannot do this scenario at compile time with constexpr (I think?)

Comment: @DarthRubik I see no reason not?  You would use factory functions that take a `char const(&)[N]` and thus know the type to be produced from incoming type information.  `operator+( static_string<N>, static_string<M> )` returns `static_string<N+M>`.  So the types are easy.  Data shouldn't be any harder?  So you'd have `constexpr auto hello = StaticString("hello");`.  Sadly user defined literals `"hello"_static` won't work as it lacks the right `operator""` overload.

Comment: @Yakk I will look into into....if I succeed I will let you know...thanks for the idea